# Add header-only library to executable in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, gsl

I am trying to include the Windows GNU GSL headers-only library (downloaded from https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm) to an example code in C++ but have lots of errors unfortunately.

Here is the structure of my repository:

```
folder/
      gsl/
          gsl_sf_bessel.h
          gsl_mode.h
          *.h # other header files
      main.cpp
      CMakeLists.txt
```

main.cpp is as such:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int main (void)
{
  double x = 5.0;
  double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
  printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

and CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(demoproject VERSION 0.1.0)


add_executable(
    demoexecutable
    main.cpp
    )

target_include_directories(
    demoexecutable
    PUBLIC
    gsl/
    )
```

The error I get when compiling is main.cpp is:

```
fatal error: gsl/gsl_mode.h: No such file or directory
[build]    26 | #include <gsl/gsl_mode.h>
```

It looks like it managed to find `gsl_sf_bessel.h` from `gsl/` but `gsl_sf_bessel.h` needs in its turn `gsl_mode.h` which the compiler cannot find. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

I tried different combinations in CMakeLists.txt of functions such as `add_library`, `include_directories`, `target_link_libraries` but nothing worked unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` as an include directory.  That is the directory that contains `gsl/gsl_mode.h`.  The `gsl` directory does not contain itself, so adding it as an include directory will not make that error go away.

Answer (score 0):

I've adopted the following practice in my CMake projects:

**1) Project's folder structure.**

Have an `include/${PROJECT_NAME}` subfolder (i.e., `include` subfolder and, within that, another subfolder named after the project's name). For example, in your case:

```
demoproject_or_whatever
|- include
|   \- demoproject
|      \- gsl
|         |- gsl_sf_bessel.h
|         \- gsl_mode.h
|- src
\- test
```

**2) src/CMakeLists.txt.**

Set an `include_dir` var at the top of the file, then use it when setting the executable's `target_include_directories`.

```
set(include_dir ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${app_sources})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${include_dir}>"
    "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>"
)
```

**3. Including header files from source files.**

Use paths relative to `include/${PROJECT_NAME}`.

```
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
```